# How work BigPipe cache around block views?

Tags: views, 8, blocks, caching

I have 2 blocks with swiper.js around.

This 2 blocks are from the views module.

I need to print them in the theme like i want so, i load them into the preprocess_page.

```
$block1 = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('views_block__test_1');
$variables['block1'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                    ->getViewBuilder('block')
                    ->view($block1);
```

And the second :

```
$block2 = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('views_block__test_2');
$variables['block2'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                    ->getViewBuilder('block')
                    ->view($block2);
```

They have exactly the same configuration in views and block config.

But for block 1 swipper work, not for the block2 every time i load the page.

If i look at the source i got this for the second block :

```
<span data-big-pipe-placeholder-id="callback=Drupal%5Cblock%5CBlockViewBuilder%3A%3AlazyBuilder&amp;args%5B0%5D=views_block__test_2&amp;args%5B1%5D=full&amp;args%5B2%5D&amp;token=3_VvuYGr92bR7BowQRNlDa4VjOC0ugQafPxRFmxKk9E"></span>
```

For the block 1 i got the HTML render.

I don't know why the second block is cached by big-pipe and not the first block.

But my js on the ready state work every time on the first block, and depend if i clear the cache but it's not everytime, work on the second block the first time i load the page.

The callback (in the bigpipe attributes) call something at the bottom of the page after the js include.

That why my second block doesn't work ? it's not clear.

What's happen ?

Comment: Does the 2nd block have an exposed filter or some sort of form/pulling in uncacheable content? Bigpipe will step in for anything deemed as uncacheable e.g. has a form. You should move your JS into a drupal behavior and that code should be triggered upon bigpipe loading in the content

Comment: nop no exposed filter, i ll try to move the js in the drupal behavior

Comment: @Leigh Mason thank put the code inside the drupal.behavior solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know why the second block is cached by big-pipe and not the
>   first block.

This depends on the auto placeholder conditions defined in services.yml and the cache metadata of the block:

```
auto_placeholder_conditions:
  # Max-age at or below which caching is not considered worthwhile.
  #
  # Disable by setting to -1.
  #
  # @default 0
  max-age: 0
  # Cache contexts with a high cardinality.
  #
  # Disable by setting to [].
  #
  # @default ['session', 'user']
  contexts: ['session', 'user']
  # Tags with a high invalidation frequency.
  #
  # Disable by setting to [].
  #
  # @default []
  tags: []
```

As mentioned in the comments, when the module BigPipe is enabled you need to use Drupal.behaviors for your javascript, see:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview